# Problem updating eclipse rcp application from 4.16 to 4.22

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am updating my eclipse rcp application from 4.16 to 4.22.

If I run my updated eclipse rcp application in an entirely new workspace, it works.

If I run my updated eclipse rcp application on top of an existing workspace that previously ran the 4.16 version, there is this error about not finding an icon (this is the project explorer icon that changed from a gif to a png file):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2022-01-31 08:37:13.602
!MESSAGE /icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.bundleentry.Handler.findBundleEntry(Handler.java:55)
```

I tried deleting everything in the workspace except the **workpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclpse.core.resources**
directory before launching my updated application, but it displays an empty application window with the following general error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-01-31 08:47:03.042
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xxx (15).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator.
```

If I close my application and launch a second time, everything works. The workspace somehow fixes itself.

Any ideas on how to fix my existing workspace before the first launch of my updated application? I do have an installer, so can perform some sort of one time fix.

Other things I have tried that result in a failed first launch, but fixed second launch:

1. Deleting the **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi** file
2. Modifying the **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi** file to reference resource_persp.png instead of resource_persp.gif

Comment: Have you tried specifying `-clean` when running the app to clear up the caches.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get the same results.

Comment: What release of Eclipse is the target platform you are using when you build your RCP? It probably needs to be 4.22

Comment: @greg-449 I am using the tycho build approach and have this repository defined:

<repository>
  <id>eclipse-release</id>
  <url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/</url>
  <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>